# Firebird crashes on `UTF8 string converted to wstring`

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, utf-8, firebird

Hi I am completely new to database. Here I am having problem inserting a row into a table. The string comes in is in Unicode and converted to UTF8 using `WideCharToMultiByte` call. Then constructed a database query as below.

```
in = "WeiÃŸ" (UTF8 string result of conversion from Unicode to UTF8)


wchar_t buf[2048]; //= new wchar_t[ in.size() ];
size_t num_chars = mbstowcs( buf, in.c_str(), in.size() );
wstring ws( buf, num_chars );
```

Here I have the string `ws = 'WeiÃ'` If I expand ws to see there are 5 characters in the string and the 5th character is `159:L''`.

```
wostringstream oss;
oss << L"insert into myutftable values("
                                       << id
                                       << L"',  '"
                                       << ws
                                       << L") ";
```

Then I am using `SQLExecDirect` to update the database. This is the place I am seeing the crash.

I am trying to understand why it crashes. I have trying few things unsuccessfully. I used `character set = utf8` but no luck. Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for crash and how to fix?

BTW I am using Firebird database version 2.0.

`UPDATE1:`

1) If I do not convert UTF8 string to wstring and use `SQLExecDirectA` call it works fine. But at this point I do not know side effects because that database has been accessing from lot other places.

2) I have tried pushing the same string from command line using isql.exe, no issues!

I wonder why in my debugger watch list the last character was not displayed (`Ÿ` this character after converting to wchar shown as `159:L''`. I looked in character set 159 refers to `Ÿ`. Any ideas why my debugger does not show this character as wchar, but it was displayed as just char?

**Is there a way to Debug `SQLExecDirect`? I am using OdbcJdbc Drivers.**

`Update 2:`
Seems like I am having issue with `Ÿ` character in my strings. As long as I am sending it in as string no issues if I use wstring at all it fails.

I just observed in memory how it was represented when I am sending it as `9f` (= Ÿ) no issues with `SQLExecDirectA` if I send it as `9f 00` (= Ÿ wchar) then it crashes on `SQLExecDirect`

My application was built using Unicode Character Set. Firebird database character set set to none.

Any ideas??

Comment: I don't think `delete [] buf` would be wise considering you never `new`d it. Just... ouch. Count on your heap being hosed after that little gem of undefined behavior. pebkac.

Comment: I agree, I do not have that call anymore in my code.

Comment: With 'crash', do you mean a Firebird server crash, connection closed, or a crash in your application?

Comment: Crash in my application as soon as I call `SQLExecuteDirect`. It did not return anything. If I construct sql statement in std::string it works fine. But if I look into database that string is not displayed correctly.

Answer (score 4):

`mbstowcs` assumes its second parameter to be a string in the system default code page, also known as `CP_ACP`, which is never UTF-8 (also known as `CP_UTF8`).

The inverse of `WideCharToMultiByte` is `MultiByteToWideChar`. Though it's unclear why you want to convert a string from Unicode to UTF-8, only to convert it right back.