# What is the difference between sending a string and wstring firebird database?

Tags: c++, string, encoding, utf-8, firebird

Hi I have a string that is in UTF-8 encoding and trying to insert in to firebird database. The insertion was successful just as UTF-8 string.

I am trying to send that UTF-8 string as wstring (conversion method below), I see that my SQLExecute statement crashing my application.

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    sC = pBuf[i];
    dC = sC;
    nString[i]= dChar;
}
```

where `pB is const char *` `sC is unsigned char` `dC is wchar_t` `nString is wstring`.

Here is the string that fails: `My StringÃŸ` (UTF-8)

after converting to wstring string looks like this `My StringÃ`, but in debugger there is one more character 159L''.

Now I wonder why it did not crash on just UTF-8 and a crash on wstring of UTF-8. What is the difference?

[Related question: Firebird crashes on `UTF8 string converted to wstring`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453849/firebird-crashes-on-utf8-string-converted-to-wstring)

Comment: There is no conversion in the code. It is just copying the two halves of the UTF-8 into two wchar_t's

Comment: Yes, there is no conversion, string should be still UTF-8 but as wchar. That is what I want

Comment: Maybe that is what you have. But the debugger is not expecting that so it will not display it correctly.